# Operção SELECT em PHP com SQL Server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server

Iniciando em PHP com SQL Server 2008.
Gostaria de saber o que há de errado com meu código.

```
<?php
$serverName = "DESKTOP-B8EB4SG\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"contas", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"123456" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (login, senha) VALUES (?, ?)";


$seleciona = "SELECT numero FROM usuarios WHERE numero=4";

echo "Opa $seleciona ";
```

Consegui inserir dados no banco de dados, mas não estou conseguindo puxar dados e jogar na variável **$seleciona**.

Quando eu acesso a pagina PHP aparece o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao executar o comando `echo` você está apenas imprimindo o conteúdo da variável `$seleciona`, mas isso não irá realizar a consulta no banco de dados e muito menos trazer o resultado desejado.

O correto é você primeiramente executar a consulta no banco de dados através do comando apropriado e depois dentro de um laço de repetição exibir o conteúdo desejado, abaixo um exemplo do que deve ser utilizado no lugar do seu `echo`:

```
// Executa a consulta
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $seleciona);
if ($stmt === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// Exibe o resultado
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['numero'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, resolveu!